# How do I use MySQL in Visual Studio 2010 with EF4?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

How do I use MySQL in Visual Studio 2010 with EF4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no MySql provider yet for EF4 and it is unlikely there will be one until after it EF4 moves out of Beta. Also it's worth mentioning that it took MySql almost 9 months to develop the initial support for EF1.
One of the third party vendors such as [DevArt](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/features.html) may come to the market sooner. Let's hope so otherwise it could be a long wait.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework)? Or do you have a specific problem with MySql and EF4?

Comment: It is different, mysql with EF works well with vs2008, but not in vs2010.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've succeeded in using EF4 with VWD express 2010 using a tool called [EdmGen2](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2).

I can't generate nor update the model trough the interface, but I've made a batch script to generate the files for EF4 and I just have to rerun the script when I change anything on my database.