# How mature is dblinq?

Tags: c#, mysql, dblinq

Im working on an application that needs to talk to a database. The application is written in C#. Im quite taken by LINQ and auto generating classes to represent the database and its tables, so first I considered using SQL as .NET only comes with support for LINQ to SQL. Right now Im leaning more to MySQL mainly because scaling the SQL server might get pricey and because the people within my company are more familiar with MySQL, including me. This is where dbLinq comes in. From what I have read dbLinq works fine for simple queries but might break down on more complicated ones. Could you share your experiences in using dbLinq? Should dbLinq still be regarded as experimental or could I expect to use it without a lot of problems?

Thanks, Bas

**Edit:**

I read that DbLinq is not able to handle more than one foreign key, can anyone comment on whether this is still the case?

Comment: @Bas -As an alternative do check out http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/ before making a decision, we've been very pleased with their Linq-to-SQL style provider and support, very economical as well.

Comment: On a scale of 1 to 10 how would you rate your database?  And is it a transactional database or a reporting database?

Comment: I'm actually having the same issue here, but I'm thinking about solving it by using SubSonic ORM.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using Entity Framework for auto generating classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about dbsql but check out Entity Framework. It allows you do Linq and can be used with MySQL.  Check out this SO question for more info on LinqToEntityFramework for MySQL [Using MySQL with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I used EntityFramework to connect to MySQL db in my last project. It is gives some minor issues but reduces amount of effort required to code. I am super impressed with it. I had to do Paging and Filtering in that application. Because of EF this was a piece of cake.

This application had very less data (fraction of millions rows). I would like to know how Entity Framework will do in Applications which has large data.