# .NET MVC 3, autogenerate/mapping model schema into Mysql?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to .net mvc 3. I was using PHP Symfony previously.

In this tutorial from the official website, the author used .sdf as example.
http://beta.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part4-cs

The schema in .sdf was autogenerated according to the Model class file.

My question, is it possible to do the same thing using Mysql?

Thanks :)

Comment: or, in other words, does MySQL support EF 4.1? [Old question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework) but doesn't mention 4.1. You might be able to do the same thing with NHibernate too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (have never used ef code first with mySql) as long as you have the .net connector for MySql.
You can grab it here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/
You can also try this alternative connector from DevArt: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/

* EDIT ***
It seems that the DevArt connector will do the [trick](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/entity-framework-code-first-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html).

Comment: or there's instructions for the MySQL connector [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283820/using-mysql-with-entity-framework-4-and-the-code-first-development-ctp/4924678#4924678) too.

Comment: Thanks :), looks like I have to create the schema myself.
It doesn't auto generate