# Provider MySQL to Code First

Tags: .net, mysql, entity-framework-4

Does anyone know any free provider for MySQL using the Entity Framework (Code First)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283820/using-mysql-with-entity-framework-4-and-the-code-first-development-ctp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL Connector/NET is sufficient to use MySQL with Entity Framework.

See

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/12/09/getting-mysql-work-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx