# Connection to Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I recently started working with Entity Framework in Visual studio.
I really love it, and how it creates the SQL database for me. 
The only thing that i cannot get to work is connecting to and setting up a MySQL database. I saw that since the `Connector/net 6.5.5`, there's some Visual Studio integration with EF, but i cannot seem to find out what exactly. 
What's the best practice to use `EF` with `MySQL`?

Comment: I've got [a blog post](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.com/2012/10/entity-framework-on-mysql.html) about that...

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem that it also creates the database for me, or  am i wrong?

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head. Does your user have permissions to create databases? If so, then the provider may not support it.

Comment: I'm connecting to localhost with a root account, so that shouldn't be problem. But what do you mean by provider may not support it? the Connector/net does not support creating databases?

Comment: It looks like versions 6.3.5 and newer can create databases. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Have you read... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283820/using-mysql-with-entity-framework-4-and-the-code-first-development-ctp

Comment: That was the solution. I read Brice's blog post, which got me a lot further, but i kept getting a "version string too short or too long" error. I put the information from the question from Paul in my app.config, and that solved it :) .