# Entity Framework 4.0 model from a database in MySQL server

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I would want your opinion about building the Entity Framework 4.0 from a database which is on a (remote) MySQL server. Is there anyone who has experienced this "combination". Perhaps some MYSQL server configuration... anything.

Thanks!

Comment: what has EF got to do with the 'remote'ness?

Comment: In my experience it worked fine with the latest version of MySql Connector/.NET; if you have any specific issues we will be able to help. The configuration for the server doesn't need anything special, just make sure the account you connect with has the necessary permissions (i.e. to connect from any IP), as you would do to connect to it using any other tool.

Comment: Actually there is one thing, MySql is case-sensitive only on *nix - on Windows it forces table names to lower case which annoyed me greatly (looks awkward in .Net in general), so I always used MySql installed on Linux or FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

Using Entity Framework with MySQL is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework).