# Which is the most popular O/R-Mapper for .Net as of 2010?

Tags: .net, orm

I am not talking about performance or price.

I am talking about popularity.

Which is the most popular O/R-Mapper for .Net as of 2010?

Which would be the most popular O/R-Mapper for .Net for years to come?

Comment: "Most popular" can be answered. "For years to come" is speculative (subjective).

Comment: Whoever answers "most popular" had better have some pretty convincing data to back it up, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would venture to say that [NHibernate](http://www.nhibernate.com/) is the incumbent, and presently most popular option. The current version (4.0 by name, 2.0 by "design") of Entity Framework (EF) has marked improvements over v1.0, which has issues that led many would-be adopters to adopt another solution, namely NHibernate, or roll their own.

As for the future, NHiberte has a solid following and is a mature product, whereas EF 4.0 needs to make amends for the many sins and shortcomings of the previous version, while still having its own issues, and being relatively young as a technology.

Comment: Can you possibly elaborate on what are the current sins and shortcomings of EF 4.0 compared to NHibernate 4.0? In other words, what can the latter do where the former falls short?

Answer (score 3):

NHibernate is most likely the biggest one right now, but MSEF is stealing its thunder (NH 3.0 has some major flaws in its Linq provider, and MSEF, though new, comes packaged with .NET 4.0)

Comment: Can you describe what the major flaws are? I'm looking into using NHibernate 3.0 myself and LINQ support is crucial to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you include everything, i'd bet Linq to SQL is the most popular, but for large projects NHibernate i'd imagine.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) has probably surpassed most other ORMs in popularity at this point, and will continue to grow faster than most in the future.

This is mainly because it's a supported part of the .NET Framework itself.  [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) predated it, so it may still (at this point) be more used, but most newer development seems to be switching over to EF, especially as it's getting a lot more attention from Microsoft.

Comment: Does EF support exotic databases like MySQL, Firebird or Informix?

Comment: I wouldn't consider MySQL 'exotic' but I have used MySQL with EF4. No clue about Firebird/Informix/Access/Excel/CSV/an abacus/parchment paper/stone tablet/etc....

Comment: @JMSA - MySQL - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework

Comment: @Alex I would have given you a thousand points for your comment. But only +1 is possible.:):):):):):):):)

Comment: @JMSA: EF is technically db neutral - though it does require some support for the provider to work.