# MySql or MS Sql Server with .Net Application

Tags: .net, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm developing a software using .Net platform.
I want to know is it better to use MySql instead of MS Sql Server Express or not?
My concern is the DBMS integration with ADO.NET and Entity Framework. Of course I don't want to rewrite the codes which Microsoft has written for integrating MS SQL Server and .Net and also ease of use(I mean wizards and ...)
The program has at last 2 or 3 users but it should transfer data to a Server running Linux, Apache and MySql, So if I choose to use MS Sql Server in my application, I should transfer data between these two DBMSes

Answer (score 1):

Well, your application is quite small (or 2-3 users) and either DB is going to support your load (assuming your not doing anything really wacky and crazy) so its really all up to your preference.  Now I wouldn't use SQL server express though, I would spend a little cash and get the full version; using developemnt level stuff for prod is a big no, no.

So in the end it looks like the your question answers itself.  Microsoft has built in nice connection between .net and sql server, might as well take advantage of it!

Comment: SQL Express is not a "development level" tool, it's used in production all over, including in Microsoft products.  It simply doesn't have all the bells and whistles of the full blown version, and if you don't need them, why pay for them?

Comment: I disagree. It only supports 1g of memory and only 1 cpu. I would never think that small when looking at a production database, even one with very few users.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Entity Framework with the mysql provider

there is a question here about it:

[Using MySQL with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework)

links to the connector here:

http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirements, I suggest you communicate with MySQL directly instead of MS SQL Server. But in normal circumstances, I would pick MS SQL Server any day, even if it's Express.