# Setting up .NET MVC3 with MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Hy Guys,

How can I configure the webconfig to access a mysql db using MVC 3?

To use SQLExpress I included this code to configure in an example...

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"
     connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;
     Database=Movies;Trusted_Connection=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'm using Entity Framework.

PS.: I don't want to automatically create tables with the MVC. I want to create them manually.

Thks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this post, it seems like your best option is to use MySql Connector with EF

[Using MySQL with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework)

your connection string should look something like:

`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`