# Entity Framework 5 with MySql - Connection string example needed for web.config

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I just need an example with a default MySQL developer installation.  I have this working fine with SQLExpress.  Here's my SQL Express connection string:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
```

What should I put to make this work for MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these posts

- [Using MySQL with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework)
- [Setting up .NET MVC3 with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887372/setting-up-net-mvc3-with-mysql)

Hope this helps

Comment: I just need the connection string for web.config.  I've read most of those articles, and can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Doug type your answer up and mark it as the answer. It may help someone else and you will get points to the answer.