# What steps are needed to use an Entity Framework model with a MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I've added and designed an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (.edmx) and have generated the corresponding DDL Script (.edmx.sql). When I was using SQL Server 2008, all I had to do was connect to it via the Transact-SQL Editor toolbar and execute the SQL. When I try this method, however, it doesn't let me connect to the MySQL server, as it seems to be looking only for Microsoft SQL Servers. I have the latest version of Connector/Net, and can add the MySQL database as a Data Connection, but cannot execute the script I need. What steps are needed to use an Entity Framework model with my MySQL server?

Comment: Check this topic if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework

Comment: @Ladislav - That's a very helpful question, but unfortunate everything I see generates the model from the database, and I'm looking to do it the other way around.

Comment: Not every connector supports creating a database from model.

Comment: I'm seeing that... unfortunately, that may be the answer to my question. =[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled across this little property while editing my Data Model:

[image: DDL Generation Property]

(This option was installed along side [Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).)

After changing to `SSDLToMySQL.tt`, right-click and select `Generate Database from Model...` as you would normally. This will generate the `.edmx.sql` file, and should give you several errors (as .NET uses SQL Server to parse `.sql` files.) After generating the DDL script, I opened up [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html) and pasted the script in. You need to make sure that an appropriately-named schema already exists on the server, then run the script, and voila.