# Switching from SQL Server Express to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, ado.net

I've built my entire app around an SQL Server Express 2008 DB and realized as time goes on that the potential to go over the 4GB limit is there. I was wonddering what I'm up against in switching from MSSQL to MySQL keeping in mind that I'm heavily using the Entity Framework and Linq.

Comment: Another Question somewhat answers your Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework

Comment: I saw this and you are correct in that it doesn't completely answer my question. I saw this blog post (http://blogs.oracle.com/MortazaviBlog/entry/ado_net_entithy_framework_on) that it can be done with no code change, but I'm skeptical.

Comment: I've decided to try out the MySQL connector with a test app to see how it runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also want to consider upgrading to SQL Server Express 2008 R2, [because MS increased the maximum database size from 4 GB to 10 GB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/04/21/database-size-limit-increased-to-10gb-in-sql-server-2008-r2-express.aspx).

If your database will not get that big, you might get away with that.
If it is likely to grow over 10 GB, then of course upgrading to SQL Server 2008 R2 doesn't help you in the long term.
But maybe upgrading to R2 at least buys you some more time to make the switch to MySQL.

---

**EDIT**
John, the download size depends on the edition of SQL Server Express. There are three editions with different sizes:

- [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3743) (about 70 MB)
- [SQL Server Express with Management Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23650) (about 250 MB)
- [SQL Server Express with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25174) (about 750 MB)

The "bigger" editions include stuff like SQL Server Management Studio and Reporting Services.
If you don't need that and just want a database, the smallest edition is enough for you.

Comment: The other issue is the installation size and complexity. Deploying with SQL Server adds a few hundred MB to the package.

Comment: Thanks Christian, I will continue with SQL Express for version 1 and explore the possibility of MySQL for future versions.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Entity, so I can't speak for that.

But for SQL Express to MySQL switch, I don't think it is small, but it isn't so big either.

The MySQL C# dll has almost all the same functions as the SQL dll does, maybe they are MySQLFunction instead of just SQLFunction.

The slight differences in queries might get you here and there, such as the use of LIMIT 100 vs TOP 100.