# Migrating from .NET 3.5 to 4.5 causing error with MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I am currently upgrading my C# project to target the .NET 4.5.1 framework.  Previously I targeted 3.5 and used to use version 6.2.2 of the MySqlConnector.  However on targeting 4.5.1 I received the below error.  I have tried upgrading MySqlConnector to version 6.9 and rebuilt all the tables using the Entity Framework tool (DDEX), but the same error occurs which is:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Every derived table must have
>   its own alias

Anyone have any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: When does the error occur - is there example code you can show?

Comment: "This is a known bug that is still not fixed after years (appeared in MySQL 5.5.22 + .Net/Connector 6.5.4 on 04/04/12)." - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056716/mysql-entity-framework-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias

Comment: Hi thanks, strange though how this works fine when targeting 3.5 frameworks, and as soon as we alter to 4.0 or higher this issue arises?

Comment: Issue occurs as soon as we try to do a GetAll var data = dataSet.FirstOrDefault();