# using linq with mysql database in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, linq

how to use linq with mysql database in vb.net,I have searched on google but did not find clear tutorial on this?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/12/09/getting-mysql-work-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx) which illustrates a step by step tutorial of how you could use EF with MySQL. All you have to do is install MySQL Connector.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this problem. Assume your MySQL table called myTable looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------+
| id | name        | phone        | office | department |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------+
|  1 | Brian Baker | 858-555-1212 | N-110  | software   |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------+
|  2 | Dana Damien | 858-555-1414 | N-120  | hardware   |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+------------+
```

Use the links in the above answer to get the connector (download the MySql.Data.dll and add it to your project references), and then use something similar to this code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class MyClass
    Public Sub getData()
        Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()

        Try
            Dim connStr As String = "Database=xxx;Data Source=xxx;User Id=xxx;
                Password=xxx;Allow Zero Datetime=true;Port=####"
            Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
            Dim query As String = "select * from myTable where department='software';"
            Dim cmd As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection)
            connection.Open()
            cmd.Fill(myDataSet)
            connection.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error opening database: " & ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        Dim employeeData As DataTable = myDataSet.Tables(0)

        Dim myQuery = From employee In employeeData.AsEnumerable()
                      Where employee.Field(Of String)(4) = "software"
                      Select New With {
                        .name = employee.Field(Of String)(1),
                        .phone = employee.Field(Of String)(2),
                        .office = employee.Field(Of String)(3)
                      }

        For Each employee In myQuery
            Console.Write("Name: " + employee.name)
            Console.Write("Phone: " + employee.phone)
            Console.WriteLine("Office: " + employee.office)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note we are accessing the columns in the Linq query by number and that they are 0-based.