# I've added a connection string, but when I add data to my site it isn't appearing in my database; where is it saving to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Title says most of it.

I've added this to my `Web.Debug.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Sharpix"
    connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=sharpix; Uid=root; Pwd=;"
    providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I'm using the MySQL driver, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/848539/65387). Presumably if I installed it incorrectly, or there was an error with it, I would get an exception, but as far as I can tell, it isn't being used, and there is no attempt at using it.

However, I can add data to my site just fine:

[image]

So where's it storing my data, and how do I get it to use my MySQL database?

If relevant, my model looks like this:

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

}

And my context looks like this:

```
public class SharpixContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ImageModel> ImageModels { get; set; }
}
```

I'm pretty much a beginner when it comes to the ASP.NET MVC, but I'm very familiar with the concept of MVC in general, and the Django framework.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the connection string name in the constructor. Otherwise EF will try to create a database named `namespace.SharpixContext` in your local server.

```
public class SharpixContext : DbContext
{
    public SharpixContext()
     : base("Sharpix")
    {}

    public DbSet<ImageModel> ImageModels { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hrm...that didnt' seem to do it. Data I had in there before went missing, but the new stuff I'm adding doesn't appear to be saving in that DB.

Comment: @Mark strange. Are you running on `Debug` mode? Does your `Web.Config` file has another connection with the same name?

Comment: Yes, I'm running in debug mode, no, no other connections. It was a fresh project. I pretty much just added the one model and then used the generator to create the controller, the context and the views.

Comment: @Mark Check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592674) on msdn for setting up connections.