# Using MySql wit linq

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq

I have 2 questions for which I need help.

1)
    I have developed an application where in I store the files(doc,xls,etc) in database. I have used LINQ to perform insert,update and delete. I have used MS SQL. Now, the requirement is that of using MySql. Can I use LINQ wit MySql. I searchd and found that LINQ only supports MS SQL and access. If it is decided that MySql should be usued, I dont want to go back to the traditional 3tier architecture. Can NHibernate can be used with MySql?

2)
    How do the blade servers perform when it has to manage a data of 500gb+ data(documents). The RAM is about 12GB. Please nedd sugggestions that if such a huge amount of data is there, is it better not to store the data(documents) in database and store it in drives on the server instead.Because I have seen that if the data is stored in database(binary format) the size does increase.

Comment: Which technology do you use? EntityFramework, LinqToSql, ...?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here we go

1) It is not possible to communicate with an MySQL-Database via Linq To Sql, like you mentioned it is only build for MSSQL and Access. Prefer using the EntityFramework to communicate with variable databases. It is nearly the same to work with like Linq To Sql. You can easily develop your application using an MSSQL-Database and switch to a MySQL-Database after deployment by just changing your ConnectionString and installing the MySQL-EntityFramework-Connector. 
These links may be helpfull to you:

- [Codeproject.com - An Introduction to Entity Framework for Absolute Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B)
- [Stackoverflow.com - Using MySQL with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework)

2) I would advise you to store your data on physical drives and set references to the stored file in your database. This is because the heavy amount of data transferred while requesting one of your documents will slow down your database for other querys that normally just would take milliseconds to be executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helps. For 2) question. If the file gets deleted from the physical location, its entry will persist in DB. It may create problems. What is your take on this?

Comment: Thanks. I can do all of the above,but the problem is the application has been developed and deployment is tommorow or day after tommorow. I cant handle this and make changes. ut any ways, thanks a ton for the valuable heelp.

Comment: For the future: Inform yourself about the repository pattern for easier changes of data acces technologies ;) best regards

Comment: What technologies you will suggest for my future use, when I undertake a project.?