# How to update the mysql table using sql server table data in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

So I have the table clienti in mysql and ClientiImporti in sql server and I want to compare at first the elements of the rows of clienti with the elements of the rows of ClientiImporti if they are equal then I have to overwrite the elements of the rows of the table clienti in mysql. I am thinking of using update but am not sure what to do. I would really help a little help thank you. I am a newbie in c#. Thanks in advance

```
int lengthClienti = MySqlSetClienti.Tables["clienti"].Rows.Count;

int columnClienti = 4;
    
//loop through all rows of Sql Server data table and add into MySql dataset
    
for (int i = 0; i <= lengthClienti - 1; i++)//row
{
    for (int j = 0; i <= columnClienti; j++)//column
    {
        if (SqlDataSet.Tables["ClientiImporti"].Rows[i][j].ToString() == MySqlSetClienti.Tables["clienti"].Rows[i][j].ToString())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your question about the algorithm of the synchronization, or the syntax for writing data to the MySQL client?

Comment: is about writing data in MySql client?

Comment: OK... I've never written to MySQL myself, but I'm personally a big fan of Entity Framework, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/76488/7850) ought to point you in the right direction.