# What kind of approach? Create new classes?

Tags: vb.net

**Hello helpful people!**

I've just recieved a new assigment where I am supposed to create an employee, inventory and administration application. I've also got a MySQL-database including all employees, items, orders, customers, history and so on.

Now, my question is how do I approach this? Should create my own classes like "Employee", "Customer" and "Inventory"? Is that the better way, considering that I have to connect the database to VB?

Please excuse me if I am not specific enough, I have little to no experience in programming, but I couldn't find a good answer online that is why I am asking you guys.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into [Object-relational mapping (ORM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

There are many which you can use. e.g [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx), [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/), [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite), [Simple.Data](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data)

They all all connect to your MySql database and build the Classes automatically. This will save you from manually coding everything.

If you search Stackoverflow for how to use each with MySql there will be many helpful answers.

To start you off with, check out this one which helps with EntityFramework and MySql [Using MySQL with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework)

Furthermore, if you want to speed things up even more, then take a look at MVC. You can create pages which allow you to interact with the database with a simple click.