# Using MySQL on development environment and SQL server on the live environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working with a commercial system by integrating with its database using Entity framework. The current environments setting is as follow:-

1.On the live environment & on the staging environment the commercial system is using SQL server 2008 r2.

2.While on the development environment, I have installed the commercial system with the default MYSQL that comes with the product. Due to licenses & resource restrictions.

I want to use entity framework to work with the database , so if I finish my development using entityframworkà MySQL,, will it take a lot of work to connect the entity framework to the SQL server on the staging environment and then on the live environment .

I am asking this as entity framework should provide an abstract level from the database , so I am assuming that only changing the connection string should work well?

Can anyone advice on this?

BR

Answer (score 1):

> While on the development environment, I have installed the commercial system with the default MYSQL that comes with the product. Due to licenses & resource restrictions.

Can't you use [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/)?

But yes, you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework) use Entity Framework with MySQL, and it *should* be possible to accomplish by just changing the connection string. Beware that the MySQL-EF connector seems not to support all possiblities of Linq to Entities.