# How to connect mvc with mysql?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, mysql-connector

I'm want to connect MVC3 website with mysql server. I'm have reference to Mysql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity, MySql.Web, Entityframework, but when i add new connection, in list provider not showing MySQL.

[image]

I have prefer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework) to do, but i don't know what wrong with me?

Comment: Your answer is at [Connector/Net Visual Studio Integration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-visual-studio.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use this dll in your project [link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
For your help use following tutorials:
[Link1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html)
[Link2](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/426790/Using-MySQL-with-Entity-Framework)

Comment: Thankiu Muhamad. I had install MySql Connector/.net 6.7.4. but don't what wrong!

Comment: You have to study mysql installer before using it read this
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html