# Update the primary key when a new row is inserted in a DataTable through a DataGrid

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, wpfdatagrid, dataadapter

I've a DataTable binded to a DataAdapter with the following C# code:

```
MySQLConnection conn = ...

string sql = "SELECT ...";
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
adapter.Fill(this); // this is the DataTable used by the grid

MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
// here the adapter.UpdateCommand/.InsertCommand/.DeleteCommand code

RowChanged += LyricsDataTable_RowModified;
RowDeleted += LyricsDataTable_RowModified;
TableNewRow += LyricsDataTable_TableNewRow;
```

Then, the DataGrid uses `dataTable.AsDataView()` as `ItemsSource` property's value.

It works fine to update or insert rows, with `adapter.Update(this);` in event handler methods.

Once it's inserted, I would like to update the primary key in the DataTable.

What's the best way to achieve that (well I could callk SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID, but I guess there is a better DAO way to get this information)?

Answer (score 0):

In our product we have a generic API that insert a data contract(in your case data table) and return the inserted data contract a long with It's primary key and MSrowversion. Our MSRowVersion is updated each time we touch this row. 
You might need to do the same. Each time you insert/update you return the updated row.
If you have time try to create your own DAL Helper.

Another easy way to do that is to use .Net Entity Framework. When you insert/update using EF it returns the latest row by default. It's ORM and It's very very easy to use, but It works with SQL server only as far as I can tell.
Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

A DataAdapter can do that. :)

3 tricks to know :

1. You have to build a customized insert command with an **output parameter** (say `@Identity`) that will retrieve the newly generated ID by calling `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` at the end of your insert query :

```sql
INSERT INTO TheTable (TheCol1, TheCol2) VALUES (@Val1, @Val2); SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

2. You have to **map the parameter** to the primary key column (see `SourceColumn` below) :

```cs
var identityParameter = theInsertCommand.CreateParameter();

identityParameter.ParameterName = "@Identity";
identityParameter.DbType = DbType.Int32; 
identityParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
identityParameter.SourceColumn = "PrimaryKeyColumnName";

theInsertCommand.Parameters.Add(identityParameter);
```

3. You **cannot reuse** an insert command built from a commandbuilder : because (for a reason I don't know) it is reset when the adapter execute the update.

Then, after calling `adapter.Update(LyricsDataTable);`, the new primary key will be automagically filled in your DataTable.

For more detailed instructions, read this article : [Retrieving Identity or Autonumber Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-identity-or-autonumber-values). The sample use a stored procedure, but it also works with a simple SQL query, like my example.