# Using a phpmyadmin database in MVC with api

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I was asked if it is possible to create an API in asp.net MVC C#, Where the MVC program will use the API to call select data from an existing websites MySQL database and display it, then be able to put this data into a SQL database. My knowledge on APIs is limited and what I am looking for out of this question is:

1. Is it possible?
2. If so is there any good tutorials, videos or other documentation you could link that would help to achieve this?
3. If it is not possible - what other options are there to do this? If any.

I have spent a good bit of time searching around to try find something on this but I don't seem to be able to find anything and am not sure where to look.

(Right now, to try to create this I have a MySQL database done in phpMyAdmin and a database done in SQL Server 2012 that are as identical as I could make them, I have no code as I don't know where to start and I am using Visual Studios 2013)

Comment: Of course there is, but it would be a lot easier if you had access to the MySql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ORM like EF6 you can check  [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/howto_using_mysql_for_visual)
If you want to go for plain SQL you can check [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/822392/Connecting-to-MySQL-from-ASP-NET-MVC-using-Visual)

Just follow one of these tutorials and you'll be up and running very soon.
I would go for plain SQL version at first to have more control over data flow and also to avoid and difficulties with Entity Framework configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You should read the MVC guide from Microsoft and work with Entity Framework but with MySQL:

StackOverflow question about it:
[Using MySQL with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework)

MVC Guide from Microsoft:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4